# BizTalk - Can you know inside an orchestration whether it is resumed?

Tags: biztalk, resume, biztalk-orchestrations

I was wondering if there is any way you can be aware inside an orchestration that it has just been resumed? I'm logging processing steps and errors from the orchestration, and it would be nice if in the error log you would see something like "Step 2 failed", and then as the next entry "Orchestration resumed at step 2".

Is there maybe some global property that is set after a resume?

Answer (score 1):

So...first some advice...

> "I'm logging processing steps and errors from the orchestration"

**Don't waste your time with this.**  Totally serious.  I've seen people put hours into this and *the result is never useful* and almost always causes more problem that it will ever help you solve.  Most important, **BizTalk Tracking already does this**.

Now, in practical terms, you will already know if the Orchestration was suspended so you're trying to log something that you already know.  And even if you do manage to logs this, again, it won't help.

Basically, you will be much better off learning how to use the built in tools, such as Tracking and the Event Log instead of spending time on something that will, trust me, never help you.  Meaning, it's a net negative.

Answer (score 0):

For an orchestration to be resumed, it first would have to become suspended.
As far as I know, there are 3 ways to suspend an orchestration:

1. A suspend shape was encountered
2. An exception occurred
3. The orchestration is manually suspended using the BizTalk Administration Console.

The first 2 cases can be easily done programmatically either by setting a variable before the suspend shape or in your exception handling.

For the last case, which doesn't occur often, I'm not sure if that is possible.